# How to plot logit and probit in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

This is almost surely a newbish question/

For the dataset below I have been trying to plot both the logit and the probit curves in ggplot2 without success.

```
Ft Temp TD

    1  66 0
    6  72 0
    11 70 1
    16 75 0
    21 75 1
    2   70 1
    7   73 0
    12 78 0
    17 70 0
    22 76 0
    3   69 0
    8   70 0
    13 67 0
    18 81 0
    23 58 1
    4   68 0
    9   57 1
    14 53 1
    19 76 0
    5   67 0
    10 63 1
    15 67 0
    20 79 0
```

The code I have been naively using is

```
    library(ggplot2)
    TD<-mydata$TD
    Temp<-mydata$Temp
    g<-    qplot(Temp,TD)+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method="glm",family="binomial",formula=y~x,col="red")
    g1<-g+labs(x="Temperature",y="Thermal Distress")
    g1
    g2<-g1+stat_smooth(method="glm",family="binomial",link="probit",formula=y~x,add=T)
    g2
```

Could you please tell me how I could improve my code so as to plot these two curves on the same graph?

Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to generate your own predicted values and plot them with ggplot—then you can have more control over the final plot (rather than relying on `stat_smooth` for the calculations; this is especially useful if you're using multiple covariates and need to hold some constant at their means or modes when plotting).

```
library(ggplot2)

# Generate data
mydata <- data.frame(Ft = c(1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 3, 8, 
                            13, 18, 23, 4, 9, 14, 19, 5, 10, 15, 20),
                     Temp = c(66, 72, 70, 75, 75, 70, 73, 78, 70, 76, 69, 70, 
                              67, 81, 58, 68, 57, 53, 76, 67, 63, 67, 79),
                     TD = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))

# Run logistic regression model
model <- glm(TD ~ Temp, data=mydata, family=binomial(link="logit"))

# Create a temporary data frame of hypothetical values
temp.data <- data.frame(Temp = seq(53, 81, 0.5))

# Predict the fitted values given the model and hypothetical data
predicted.data <- as.data.frame(predict(model, newdata = temp.data, 
                                        type="link", se=TRUE))

# Combine the hypothetical data and predicted values
new.data <- cbind(temp.data, predicted.data)

# Calculate confidence intervals
std <- qnorm(0.95 / 2 + 0.5)
new.data$ymin <- model$family$linkinv(new.data$fit - std * new.data$se)
new.data$ymax <- model$family$linkinv(new.data$fit + std * new.data$se)
new.data$fit <- model$family$linkinv(new.data$fit)  # Rescale to 0-1

# Plot everything
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Temp, y=TD)) 
p + geom_point() + 
  geom_ribbon(data=new.data, aes(y=fit, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_line(data=new.data, aes(y=fit)) + 
  labs(x="Temperature", y="Thermal Distress")
```

[image: Better single line]

*Bonus, just for fun*: If you use your own prediction function, you can go crazy with covariates, like showing how the model fits at different levels of `Ft`:

```
# Alternative, if you want to go crazy
# Run logistic regression model with two covariates
model <- glm(TD ~ Temp + Ft, data=mydata, family=binomial(link="logit"))

# Create a temporary data frame of hypothetical values
temp.data <- data.frame(Temp = rep(seq(53, 81, 0.5), 2),
                        Ft = c(rep(3, 57), rep(18, 57)))

# Predict the fitted values given the model and hypothetical data
predicted.data <- as.data.frame(predict(model, newdata = temp.data, 
                                        type="link", se=TRUE))

# Combine the hypothetical data and predicted values
new.data <- cbind(temp.data, predicted.data)

# Calculate confidence intervals
std <- qnorm(0.95 / 2 + 0.5)
new.data$ymin <- model$family$linkinv(new.data$fit - std * new.data$se)
new.data$ymax <- model$family$linkinv(new.data$fit + std * new.data$se)
new.data$fit <- model$family$linkinv(new.data$fit)  # Rescale to 0-1

# Plot everything
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Temp, y=TD)) 
p + geom_point() + 
  geom_ribbon(data=new.data, aes(y=fit, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, 
                                       fill=as.factor(Ft)), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_line(data=new.data, aes(y=fit, colour=as.factor(Ft))) + 
  labs(x="Temperature", y="Thermal Distress")
```

[image: Better multiple lines]

Comment: this is very elegant, but by constructing your own (Normal-based) confidence intervals rather than using `glm`, you are getting confidence intervals exceeding the (0,1) range, which is probably *not* what the OP wants ...

Comment: Good point. I reworked the answer following Hadley's approach in ggplot, predicting using the link function and then transforming it to the response scale. All is well now.

Comment: Also, all the data frame creation could be streamlined significantly with `dplyr`, but I kept with base R for this answer.

Comment: What I really found myself wanting to be able to do, given that (in my own case) I wish to display a logistic binomial regression like this, but, in the plot, keep the yes/no or true/false nature of the y-axis so-labelled, rather than getting this 0 to 1 gradient instead.

But if I try to use a factor, well.. I get a really nice chart, but lose the ability to plot the regression line.

Comment: You can use `scale_y_continuous()` to define breaks and labels in the y axis, like so: `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))`

Comment: Is there as easier way to get the conf.int by using the argument `type="response"` in `predict` (i.e. instead of calling `model$family$linkinv`)?

Answer (score 3):

These two functions that you use in stat_smooth overlap. This is why you think you can't see those two on the same graph. Running the below will make this clear having a blue colour for the second line.

```
library(ggplot2)
TD<-mydata$TD
Temp<-mydata$Temp
g <- qplot(Temp,TD)+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method="glm",family="binomial",formula=y~x,col="red")
g1<-g+labs(x="Temperature",y="Thermal Distress")
g1
g2<-g1+stat_smooth(method="glm",family="binomial",link="probit",formula=y~x,add=T,col='blue')
g2
```

If you run a different family on the second stat_smooth, for example a poisson glm:

```
library(ggplot2)
TD<-mydata$TD
Temp<-mydata$Temp
g <- qplot(Temp,TD)+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method="glm",family="binomial",formula=y~x,col="red")
g1<-g+labs(x="Temperature",y="Thermal Distress")
g1
g2<-g1+stat_smooth(method="glm",family="poisson",link="log",formula=y~x,add=T,col='blue')
g2
```

Then you can see that indeed two lines are plotted:

[image]

Comment: stylistically I would prefer `ggplot(mydata,aes(Temp,TD))+geom_point()+ ...` to make it even clearer add `fill='red'`, `fill='blue'` to the respective graphs to colour in the ribbons ... PS It doesn't really make much sense to compare a logit-binomial with a log-Poisson  ... I think you really want `link="logit"` not `link="log"` ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks Ben. My point was to show that his code worked and that the two lines he plotted overlapped. The easiest way to do that was to change the second glm model to something different to make it clear. I am not trying to compare the two models in any way. I am not trying to compare a logit-binomial with a log-Poisson. Also, yes stylistically there are a 10000 ways to make my graph better but I just wanted a fast way to make my point clear. Thanks.