# How to plot log odds for a binary outcome against a continuous variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I am trying to generate some graphs to visualize the functional form of different variables for exploratory data analysis and simple modeling. I have a binary outcome variable, and some continuous predictor variables. What I would like to do is make a graph in `ggplot2` that compares the log odds of my outcome variable in the Y axis to the predictor variable in the X-axis. This way I can visually estimate if the predictor variable needs to be transformed before using it in a linear regression.

Disclaimer: I am a novice at both R and Statistics.

So far the closes thing I've found is in the `Hmisc` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)

df <- mtcars %>% mutate(mpg = if_else((mpg > 18), 1, 0))

plsmo(
  df$hp,
  df$mpg,
  method = "lowess",
  datadensity = TRUE,
  ylab = "Log odds of mpg > 18 as a function of hp",
  fun = plogis,
  lty = 3
)
```

Even in this case, it doesn't quite make a scatterplot of the outcome variables, and instead represents the data densities in the form of the tick marks on the line. If I could at least replicate that graph, it might be a good starting point. My first thought would be to do it manually by breaking the predictor variable into bins and calculating the odds for each bin, but this might require a large degree of fiddling for each graph.

[This is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694931/how-to-plot-logit-and-probit-in-ggplot2) but doesn't help much with seeing relationships.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the code you attached isn't giving you what you want? I'm not super familiar with the function, but from the Hmisc documentation it sounds like the tick marks *are* the scatter plot (i.e., the raw x values on the horizontal axis, the smoothed log odds on the vertical)? You can also remove the line with `lines = F`. P.S. you might want to add `library(dplyr)` to your code to make it reproducable :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The `tidyverse` package includes `dplyr` and `ggplot2`, but you're right it's not specific. My read of the documentation is that the tick marks are a density distribution whose Y-position is determined by the smoothing function, rather than by the log odds. What I can't figure out is how it determines the bin size for each frequency count.

Comment: To plot log odds, you need log odds. Your data is binary, so you need to calculate log odds - and as you don't have much data (all your x values are unique!), the most straightforward way to calculate log odds is a binomial glm. So fit a model, pull out the predicted log odds of y for each x, and plot that curve, along with your observed points. This is the approach of the question you link, and is standard.

Comment: As per your comment, Hmisc uses *lo*cally *we*ighted *s*moothing (lowess) as you specify in the call. You can look that up on wikipedia, it's sort of a continuous equivalent of binning. If you did your own binning, it would just approximate that. As you say, manually binning could be fiddly. You are already using the alternative.

Comment: Overall, I'm voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking" - I half understand what you see as the drawbacks of the two good approaches you've mentioned/tried, but I don't think you really understand what you *do* want unless it's a magic pony - a way to plot "the true relationship" when you only have a little bit of noisy data.

Comment: @Gregor I think your first comment has my answer. My only follow up question is, when you suggest I "plot that curve [from the GLM] along with your observed points," how would I plot the observed points except as 1s and 0s?

Comment: You would plot them as 1s and 0s. That's what was observed. You have two options: plot raw data or plot modeled data. The least parametric of a model you could do is bin data, but (at least in this example data set) you don't have enough data for that to be useful. The next least parametric model would be the lowess, and a GLM is very parametric. Plot as many of those as you want, but you can't change that your raw data is binary.