# r betareg predict(...) equivalent to the GLM predict(....)

Tags: r, glm

**Context:**
Using the [`betareg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/index.html) package to reproduce [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26695292/152860)

I think it boils down to getting `betareg` equivalent of the GLM `predict(...)`

```
# Generate data
mydata <- data.frame(Ft = c(1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 3, 8, 
                            13, 18, 23, 4, 9, 14, 19, 5, 10, 15, 20),
                     Temp = c(66, 72, 70, 75, 75, 70, 73, 78, 70, 76, 69, 70, 
                              67, 81, 58, 68, 57, 53, 76, 67, 63, 67, 79),
                     TD = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))

# Run logistic regression model
model <- glm(TD ~ Temp, data=mydata, family=binomial(link="logit"))

# Create a temporary data frame of hypothetical values
temp.data <- data.frame(Temp = seq(53, 81, 0.5))

# Predict the fitted values given the model and hypothetical data
predicted.data <- as.data.frame(predict(model, newdata = temp.data, 
                                        type="link", se=TRUE))

glimpse(predicted.data)

  Observations: 57
  Variables: 3
  $ fit            <dbl> 2.73827620, 2.62219483, 2.50611346, 2.39003209, 2.27395072, 2.15786934, 2.0...
  $ se.fit         <dbl> 1.7132157, 1.6620929, 1.6111659, 1.5604536, 1.5099778, 1.4597631, 1.4098372...
  $ residual.scale <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
```

AFAICT the `betareg` function `predict(...)` does not produce the `se.fit` values which are required to display the Confidence Interval ribbon in the chart.

Does anyone know how to mimic the GLM `predict(...)` in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the package 'effects' and the function allEffects()

```
BetaReg <- betareg(Value~x, data = Data)
Effects <- as.data.frame(allEffects(BetaReg, xlevels=list(x=BetaReg$x)))$x
Effects
```

I think it is correct (looks about right on a graph) :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this "answer" establishes that the question is non-trivial, and points to a partial solution.

1. The `zoib` package: This package provides se values but only for the sample data.  SE estimates for predicted values based on new data is not implemented.  Worked example to follow when I get a chance.
2. The `betareg` package: **Appendix B** of the following paper contains required formula.
   Ferrari, S.L.P., and Cribari-Neto, F. (2004). [Beta Regression for Modeling Rates and Proportions](https://www.ime.usp.br/~sferrari/beta.pdf). Journal of Applied Statistics, 31(7), 799–815
   It does not appear that the calculation of a Std. Error for the predicted values has been implemented in the `betareg` package.

Happy to stand corrected.