# How to extend logistic regression plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, logistic-regression, r-caret

[image: Here is the plot I created]I have created a logistic model on R, the issue is my max x value is 0.85 hence the plot stops at this value.

Is there a way I can extend this to plot to x=100 and y values calculated using my logistic model?

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(caTools)

my_data2 <- read.csv('C:/Users/Magician/Desktop/R files/Fnaticfirstround.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_data2
#converting Map names to the calculated win probability
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Dust2", "Map"] <- 0.307692
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Inferno", "Map"] <- 0.47619
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Mirage", "Map"] <- 0.708333
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Nuke", "Map"] <- 0.444444
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Overpass", "Map"] <- 0.333333
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Train", "Map"] <- 0.692308
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Vertigo", "Map"] <- 0
my_data2[my_data2$Map == "Cache", "Map"] <- 0.857143
#converting W and L to 1 and 0
my_data2$WinorLoss <- ifelse(my_data2$WinorLoss == "W", 1,0)
my_data2$WinorLoss <- factor(my_data2$WinorLoss, levels = c(0,1))

#converting Map to numeric characters
my_data2$Map <- as.numeric(my_data2$Map)

#Logistic regression model
glm.fit <- glm(WinorLoss ~ Map, family=binomial, data=my_data2)

summary(glm.fit)
#make predictions on the training data
glm.probs <- predict(glm.fit, type="response")

glm.pred <- ifelse(glm.probs>0.5, 1, 0)

attach(my_data2)
table(glm.pred,WinorLoss)

mean(glm.pred==WinorLoss)

#splitting the data for trying and testing
Split <- sample.split(my_data2, SplitRatio = 0.7)
traindata <- subset(my_data2, Split == "TRUE")
testdata <- subset(my_data2, Split == "FALSE")


glm.fit <- glm(WinorLoss ~ Map, 
               data=traindata, 
               family="binomial")
glm.probs <- predict(glm.fit,
                     newdata=testdata,
                     type="response")
glm.pred <- ifelse(glm.probs > 0.5, "1", "0")

table(glm.pred, testdata$WinorLoss)

mean(glm.pred == testdata$WinorLoss)

summary(glm.fit)

#changing the x axis to 0-100%, min map win prob - max map win prob
newdat <- data.frame(Map = seq(min(traindata$Map), max(traindata$Map), len=100))
newdat$WinorLoss = predict(glm.fit, newdata=newdat, type="response") 


p <- ggplot(newdat, aes(x=Map,y=WinorLoss))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm",
              method.args = list(family="binomial"),
              se = FALSE) +
              xlim(0,1) +
              ylim(0,1)
```

I have tried extending the x value to 100 but that just extended the axis but did not calculate the corresponding y value and hence plot these values..

Comment: `geom_smooth(fullrange = TRUE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your data, so I will show how to do it using the "challenger disaster" example (see this [LINK](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/engrwords/final_reports/Sidford_A_Individual_case_study_report_v5.pdf)), with confidence interval ribbons.

You should create artificial points in your data and fit it before plotting.

Next time, try to use `reprex` or provide a minimal reproducible example.

*Preparing data and model fitting:*

```
library(dplyr)

fails <- c(2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

temp <- c(53, 66, 68, 70, 75, 78, 57, 67, 69, 70, 75, 79, 58, 67, 70, 72, 76, 80, 63, 67, 70, 73, 76)

challenger <- tibble::tibble(fails, temp)

orings = 6
challenger <- challenger %>%
  dplyr::mutate(resp = fails/orings)

model_fit <- glm(resp ~ temp, 
                 data = challenger, 
                 weights = rep(6, nrow(challenger)),
                 family=binomial(link="logit"))

##### ------- this is what you need: -------------------------------------------

# setting limits for x axis
x_limits <- challenger %>%
  dplyr::summarise(min = 0, max = max(temp)+10)

# creating artificial obs for curve smoothing -- several points between the limits
x <- seq(x_limits[[1]], x_limits[[2]], by=0.5)

# artificial points prediction
# see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694931/how-to-plot-logit-and-probit-in-ggplot2
temp.data = data.frame(temp = x) #column name must be equal to the variable name

# Predict the fitted values given the model and hypothetical data
predicted.data <- as.data.frame(
  predict(model_fit, 
          newdata = temp.data, 
          type="link", se=TRUE)
  )

# Combine the hypothetical data and predicted values
new.data <- cbind(temp.data, predicted.data)
##### --------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Compute confidence intervals
std <- qnorm(0.95 / 2 + 0.5)
new.data$ymin <- model_fit$family$linkinv(new.data$fit - std * new.data$se)
new.data$ymax <- model_fit$family$linkinv(new.data$fit + std * new.data$se)
new.data$fit <- model_fit$family$linkinv(new.data$fit)  # Rescale to 0-1
```

*Plotting:*

```
library(ggplot2)

plotly_palette <- c('#1F77B4', '#FF7F0E', '#2CA02C', '#D62728')

p <- ggplot(challenger, aes(x=temp, y=resp))+ 
  geom_point(colour = plotly_palette[1])+ 
  geom_ribbon(data=new.data, 
              aes(y=fit, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), 
              alpha = 0.5, 
              fill = '#FFF0F5')+
  geom_line(data=new.data, aes(y=fit), colour = plotly_palette[2]) + 
  labs(x="Temperature", y="Estimated Fail Probability")+
  ggtitle("Predicted Probabilities for fail/orings with 95% Confidence Interval")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))

p

# if you want something fancier:
# library(plotly)
# ggplotly(p)
```

*Result:*

[image]

*Interesting Fact About the Challenger Data:*

NASA Engineers used linear regression to estimate the likelihood of O-ring failure. If they had used a more appropriate technique for their data, such as logistic regression, they would have noticed that the probability of failure at lower temperatures (such as ~ 36F at launch time) was extremely high. The plot shows us that for ~36F (a temperature which we extrapolate from the observed ones), we have a probability of ~0.75. If we consider the confidence interval ... well, the accident was pretty much a certainty.